# minishift unnable to pull openshift/origin:v3.7.1

Tags: docker, openshift, minishift

I am trying to get my hands dirty using minishift. While trying to install minishift, I am observing the below error.

```
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin:v3.7.1 ...
Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
-- Checking OpenShift client ... OK
-- Checking Docker client ... OK
-- Checking Docker version ... OK
-- Checking for existing OpenShift container ... OK
-- Checking for openshift/origin:v3.7.1 image ...
   Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
FAIL
   Error: error pulling Docker image openshift/origin:v3.7.1
   Caused By:
     Error: Error response from daemon: {"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/openshift/origin/manifests/v3.7.1: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Aopenshift%2Forigin%3Apull\u0026service=registry.docker.io: Proxy Authentication Required"}
Error during 'cluster up' execution: Error starting the cluster.
```

Steps to reproduce:

1) Install minishift

2) `> minishift start --vm-driver=virtualbox --iso-url file://C:/Users/Admin/.minishift/cache/iso/minishift-b2d.iso`

Comment: What minishift version are you using? Are you behind a corporate firewall where need to use a proxy?

Comment: It is 1.13.1 and the OC version is  3.7.1. I am using windows machine for this.

Comment: Agreed with Graham, this looks like something is blocking your access to auth.docker.io. I would recommend possibly trying another machine or another network connection to rule anything out. For reference, the above commands are working for me.

Comment: Yes, I am behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: Now I have tried the same by connecting to my mobile hotspoot but the issue still exists but with a different error.

Comment: Pulling image openshift/origin:v3.6.1
FAIL
   Error: error pulling Docker image openshift/origin:v3.6.1
   Caused By:
     Error: Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/openshift/origin/images: http: error connecting to proxy http://10.4.7.10:3128: dial tcp 10.4.7.10:
3128: i/o timeout